# Quais são os benefícios da orientação a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Encapsulamento permite isolar mudanças no código da implementação sem afetar a interface oferecida pela classe. Não deixa o estado interno se comprometer com o cliente da classe (promove ocultação da informação). Também ajuda na coesão e no DRY.

Abstração é uma vantagem para gerenciar complexidade ao se trabalhar com sistemas complexos com nossas mentes limitadas. Classes são abstrações, que podem se empilhar em diferentes níveis ou camadas.

Herança promove abstração e reúso.

Polimorfismo promove o que mesmo?

Ah... e tudo isso cura câncer.

Quais são os propalados (e os reais) benefícios da orientação a objetos? No que ela é boa?

Comment: "Tudo isso cura câncer" ^^ esperando pela resposta-aula que virá...

Comment: Também questiono se é dup, ainda não tenho uma posição, preciso reler tudo lá. De qualquer forma o resumo está na pergunta OOP serve pra lidar melhor com a complexidade, só isso. Aí tem uns pontos específicos a serem falados. Fico pensando se eu não deveria dar uma resposta lá, só será triste porque a minha sempre ficará lá embaixo como se fosse errada.

Comment: Relendo as respostas lá, eu tinha voado positivamente em duas e até agora me pergunto porque não negativei a outra que mistura coisas, fala um monte de bobagem, não sei se elas responderam bem o que foi perguntado. A do Luiz Viera até responde no final, não a considero canônica, mas é uma resposta boa, o início parece um pouco perdida. A do mgibsonbr é muito boa, mas acho que responde menos, até porque muito do que ele fala ali vale para outras coisas, e acho até que eles falam de modularização mais que OOP :D. Ok, falam um pouco. Os comentadores são bem infelizes ali. Eu não sei se eu...

Comment: ...responderia melhor, por isso acho que não vou tentar, mas falta resposta real ali. São respostas úteis, mas não definitivas. Isso não quer dizer que aqui ainda não seja duplicata. Mas ainda estou em cima do muro, por isso esperando mais gente se pronunciar. Pena, fds é só tumbleweed. E é aquele negócio, se já é difícil definir OO direito, imagina achar os benéficos que dependem da definição :) Tem vantagem que foi citada lá que dá pra dizer que é uma face de uma moeda que traz tb desvantagem.